# Django html template:According to selection of category how can get subcategory list in drop down which are belongs to selected category

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I am doing a django application. I need to select category and subcategory both lists I am passing from views.py. Subcategory list had a foreign key of category list. To display lists in drop down I am using this code:

```
<label class="black">Product Category</label>
<select name="prodcatlist" >
{% for id in prodcatlist %}
    <option value="{{id.id}}" selected="selected">{{id.Name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>

<label class="black">Product Sub Category</label>
<select name="ProdSubcatList",id="ProdSubcatList" >
{% for id in ProdSubcatList %}
    <option value="{{id.id}}" selected="selected">{{id.Name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

With this I am getting all subcategory list in drop down. It is big list, so I am getting confuse to choose subcategory which is belongs to selected category. For that I want to display only subcategory list which will contains Id of selected category.

Comment: You may want to use _smart selects_ https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects. There is already some information about this on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use XHR (or a prebuilt array, of course) in the `onchange` of the category pulldown to get all subcategories for the selected category, and then populate the subcategory pulldown with those.

Comment: Can you please explain me in detail how to use XHR with an example